# Pixel Data Length mismatch to Buffer Geometry Vertices Length - Three.js

Tags: three.js, mapbox, buffer-geometry

I am using Mapbox RGB tiles to get elevation data and update Plane Buffer Geometries in Three.js. Then I am planning on using their satellite texture to complete the 3D terrain tile mesh generation. After that I will create a dynamic loading grid system.

Now my problem is that I am getting more image pixel data than vertices. This means that I can't map the pixel data to the vertices Z value for height. I did a quick plug and check to see if I could just get a fixed height and width segment that would work but it does not.

For context the image tiles are at 512x512 resolution. The pixel data length is `520849` and the Float32Array length of the buffer geometry is `519168`

Below is the rough code I have that was intended for use in creating a dataset to be served over REST API sending ThreeJSON.

```js
import * as THREE from "three";
import fs from "fs";
import Canvas from "canvas";
import path from "path";

const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(""));

async function getPixels(imagePath) {
  try {
    const data = await fs.promises.readFile(
      __dirname + imagePath,
      function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const img = new Canvas.Image(); // Create a new Image
        img.src = data;

        // Initialize a new Canvas with the same dimensions
        // as the image, and get a 2D drawing context for it.
        const canvas = new Canvas(img.width, img.height);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 4, img.height / 4);

        const imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        return imgData;
      }
    );
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

function rgbToHeight(r, g, b) {
  return -10000 + (r * 256 * 256 + g * 256 + b) * 0.1;
}

export const tileToMesh = async (rgbTilePath, textureTilePath) => {
  try {
    const pixels = await getPixels(rgbTilePath);
    const planeSize = parseInt(Math.sqrt(pixels.length / 4));

    const geometry = new THREE.default.PlaneGeometry(
      planeSize,
      planeSize,
      415,415
    //   planeSize - 1,
    //   planeSize - 1
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
      const r = pixels[i + 0];
      const g = pixels[i + 1];
      const b = pixels[i + 2];
      const height = rgbToHeight(r, g, b);

      if (!geometry.vertices[i / 4]) {
        console.error(`No vertices at index ${i / 4} found.`);
        break;
      }
      geometry.vertices[i / 4].z = height;
    }

    geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

    const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(textureTilePath);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: DoubleSide,
      wireframe: true,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    return mesh;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: What dimensions does the loaded image have when you access `img.width, img.height`? It doesn't make sense that a 512*512 image would yield 520849, since `512 * 512 * 3 = 786,432`. Additionally, you're assigning 415 subdivisions to your plane, so that's why you're getting `416 * 416 * 3 = 519,168` (it adds 1 because you need the edge vertices too).

Comment: HI @Marquizzo, the images are confirmed 512x512. I was imagining that I could match up the length as a multiple  of some sorts and then / 3 if needed ... but they don't go in without a remainder...  

Okay I figured out there was a problem with one of the function references and the buffer length was the same no matter what for the pixel data. in logging out imgData is see that it is like soo... imgData: ImageData {
    data: Uint8ClampedArray(1048576) [ ... however it is returned from the getPixels function as a buffer with 520799 bytes

Comment: https://github.com/mpaccione/everest_flight_sim/tree/debugger-mapbox-tiles to see full code if your curious